# make element at least a certain *height*

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a center page column design that simulates a piece of paper.  On some pages there is hardly any content, however, I would like to keep the middle column at least, say, 1000px, even if there isn't that much content (to keep the footer at the bottom of their viewing screen).  Of course, where there IS more than 1000px's worth of vertical content I would like for the page to scroll normally.  Is there an idiomatic way to go at least?  Would it be wise to use javascript, can you use javascript?

Comment: css min-height property?

Comment: Please accept an answer, if you need any further help, maybe implementing it, give me a shout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use CSS min-height.

```
min-height:1000px;
```

This way you will have at least a height of 1000 px but if the content is larger it will automatically expand.

Comment: Min height is god but it won't make a footer stick to the bottom of the page, css sticky footer will (see link below). With that you can use min-height: 1000px on the wrapper div which will work perfectly.

Comment: easy enough.  i hate forgetting such simple things.  thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at css sticky footer, at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com, I think this is what you are looking for! Also, you can set a div (The wrapper div) with a min-height: 1000px. This should help you.